# Trigger web service requests with delay in the test case in SOAP UI for Load testing

Tags: load, soapui

I've a scenario where the requests in a test case should be triggered with a delay. I know how to maintain the delay between the threads but unable to get on how to trigger the requests in a test case with a delay.

For ex(taken from community.smartbear.com):
[image]
Here we have three requests, Datasource, mediate-Request 1 & Datasource Loop in a load test case. I need to have these three tests run with a particular delay(say 10 secs)

Any suggestions here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Delay` type test step where you need to wait such as before running the steps or in between the existing steps as well.

For more details, refer [SoapUI's Documentation](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/teststep-reference/delay-teststep.html).

By the way, I am assuming that the objective is to just run the test case multiple times and the load test of the application as `Delay` would impact the statistics.

Comment: Thanks Rao it is working as I expected. The objective here is to check that the response is successful after a delay as well. Application under test, throws an error when we first submit the request and gives success for the rest of the consecutive requests. So delay in time is to capture the responses that were unsuccessful.